# Android Automotive types.hal changes not getting auto generted

Tags: android, android-automotive

I need some information on types.hal and VehiclePropertyIds.java .
I have added new property in types.hal as follows,

**types.hal** File changes,

```
enum ButtonStatus : int32_t {
    ON = 1,
    OFF = 2
};

/**
 * SunRoofButton
 * @change_mode VehiclePropertyChangeMode:ON_CHANGE
 * @access VehiclePropertyAccess:READ_WRITE
 * @data_enum ButtonStatus
*/
    SunRoof =(
        0x0602
        | VehiclePropertyGroup:VENDOR
        | VehiclePropertyType:INT32
        | VehicleArea:SEAT),
        
What should i do next to get these ids generated in **VehiclePropertyId.java**
Currently am doing following 3 steps 

**Commands :** 

. build/envsetup.sh
lunch aosp_car_x86-userdebug
make -j8

By this the build is successful but i don't see these entries generated in vehiclePropertyIds.java
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not supposed to edit the HAL directly.

Vehicle HAL is extendable in other way: you just define your SunRoof property as an integer in a place you want to use it (you can reference VehiclePropertyGroup and other enums or just hardcode 0x25400602 for quick and dirty testing). That would be probably your HAL implementation and the user facing app.

However, please double check if:

- you want to associate your SunRoof button with seat area (does every seat have its own sunroof button?) or just global area
- you don't want to reuse WINDOW_VENT_POS nor WINDOW_VENT_MOVE